# Extension of homeomorphisms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homeomorphism

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be smooth injective and let $n\leq m$.  Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $\iota_m^{m+k}:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+k}$ be the canonical inclusion.  Suppose also that $f(\mathbb{R}^n)\cong \mathbb{R}^n\cong g(\mathbb{R}^n)$ via some $C^{\infty}$-diffeomorphism.

Fix a compact subset $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.  For what values of $k$, does there exist a homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+k}$ satisfying
$$
\iota_m^{m+k}\circ f(x)= \phi\circ \iota_m^{m+k}\circ g(x) \qquad (\forall x \in K)?
$$
It isn't difficult to see that $k\leq m+n$.  However, what is the *smallest* such value of $k$ for which this holds?  My intuition says 1...

---

### *Reduction to Extension Problem*

I guess since $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms onto their image then, $h:=g\circ f^{-1}:f(K)\rightarrow g(K)$ is a homomorphism.  So the problem reduces to finding an extension of $h$ to all of $\mathbb{R}^{m+k}$.  But when does such an extension exist?

Comment: No, not even if you ask that $f$ and $g$ be proper. For instance, any (long) knot in $\mathbb R^3$ gives an example.

Comment: @MarcoGolla  I refined my question to bypass this pathology.  So now, this comment implies that $k\geq 1$.  Also, it is easy to see that $k\leq n+m$.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It seems $f$ and $\phi \circ \iota_m^{m+k} \circ g$ don't have the same target.

Comment: Ah, you mean it should read $\iota_m^{m+k}\circ f$?  Sorry about the notation abuse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like [the Klee trick](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-078-01/S0002-9947-1955-0069388-5/). If $K,K' \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are compact and homeomorphic, it gives a construction of a self-homeomorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that $\iota_n^{2n}(K) = \phi(\iota_n^{2n}(K'))$.

Comment: @skuppers, just one question.  Will $\phi$ preserve orientation in general?

Comment: You can assume it does by composing with a reflection that is the identity on the image of $\iota_n^{2n}$ if necessary.

Comment: A nice reference for the Klee trick is Chapter 3 of https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~sferry/ps/geotop.pdf.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I'll take a careful look :)

Comment: I was thinking some more about this.  Does a dual result also hold?  That is, if $f,g:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are retracts; can we use Klee's trick to get the dual result to infer the existence of an auto-homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$ taking $f(K)$ to $g(K)$?